# Unable to ssh to remote server

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, ubuntu, ssh, amazon-lightsail

I'm trying to log in to a particular user on my lightsail account via ssh but I get a permission denied (public key) error

Here are the steps I followed(I am on git bash on windows 8)

1. ssh into my lightsail account via the .pem key provided via aws

   `ssh -i <key.pem> ubuntu@<public_ip_address>`

(I am now logged in to my lightsail server)

1. `sudo adduser user1`
2. `sudo touch /etc/sudoers.d/user1`
3. `sudo nano /etc/sudoers.d/user1`

** user1 ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL**

4. `su - user1`
5. `sudo mkdir .ssh`
6. `sudo touch .ssh/authorized_keys`

I open Another shell prompt and do the following

-`ssh-keygen`

-`cat <file_location_of_key>.pub`

-copy the contents

7. paste the contents of the public key created on my local machine
   via ssh-keygen
8. sudo chmod 700 .ssh
9. sudo chmod 600 .ssh/authorized_keys
10. sudo service ssh restart
11. exit

I exit from the lightsail account and try to ssh to the grader user

```
ssh -i <file_location_of_key> user1@<public_ip_address>
```

I get the error Permission denied (publickey).

Note: I havn't changed any port setting yet. I’m still trying to connect it to my default port 22

Comment: No need to restart `ssh` or add user to `sudoers`. Post the output of `ssh -vvv  -i <file_location_of_key> user1@<public_ip_address>`

Comment: When you copied the contents of the public key, you might want to check that it didn't copy with line breaks.   So instead of getting one continuous string for your public key, it could have a line break after each line and it's hard to tell by just looking at it, if that's the case.    If you're on a mac a good option is to 'cat keyfile.pub | pbcopy'

Comment: @RickBaker it didn't have any line breaks. it's a single continuous line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@RickBaker @helloV Thanks for your help. Realised the file was still owned by root. Had to change to ownership of the file to user1. ssh works fine now